# In MVC pattern, which is better to use HttpSession between Controller or Service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, session, model-view-controller

Currently, by declaring HttpSession inside Service, session is created and the value for the key is retrieved.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FormAnswerService {
    private final FormAnswerRepository formAnswerRepository;

    private final FormContentService formContentService;
    private final MemberService memberService;
    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    public List<Long> createFormAnswer(Map<Long,String> answer) {
        List<Long> formAnswerIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
        Long memberId;
        if(httpSession.getAttribute("login-user") != null) {
            memberId = (Long)httpSession.getAttribute("login-user");
        }
```

Is the above expression correct? Or is it correct to validate session in Controller in the first place?

Comment: If your service depends on the servlet spec, generally you are doing things the wrong way. Instead that code should be in the controller and the id passed to the service. The controller is the integration/conversion from the web to something your service can handle (and vice versa for the response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring mvc session is usually used on controller. In spring you can use @SessionAttributes annotation to define session attributes on class scope and @ModelAttribute annotation in method scope.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("login-user")
@RequestMapping("/formAnswer")
public class FormAnswerController {
    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public String handleFromAnswerRequest(@ModelAttribute("login-user") LoginUser loginUser, 
                                          Model model, 
                                          HttpServletRequest request) {
        .......
    }    
}
```